# Spark Pi Applications running on Ideal Dataproc Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

I witness a lot of Spark Pi application runs on my ideal Dataproc Cluster. These runs took place every 5 minutes on different workers and master node. My cluster is linked to a PHS, these Spark Pi jobs end up spamming the PHS Spark UI.

Any reason why Spark Pi jobs are running on the cluster? Also any way to disable these Spark Pi jobs?

Comment: Does this [article](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/jobs/kill) by Google help you to solve your problem.Let me know if this helps.